# I am not able to clear cookies when my Test case fails

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-session

Whenever my test case fails i need to go & clear the cookies manually form cypress dashboard browser otherwise my url does not load whenever i re-run the test case

```
describe('My Test Suite', () => {


beforeEach(() => {
    cy.fixture('login').then((loginData) => {
      data = loginData
      cy.clearCookies()
      cy.clearLocalStorage()
      cy.login(data.UserName, data.Password)
    })
  })


it('Click on Project Inventory & verify Headers', () => {

    CustPage.ProjectInventoryIcon().click()
})


afterEach(() => {
    cy.clearCookies()
    CustPage.MenuContainer().click()
    CustPage.Logout().click()
  })
```

I tried the above code but when my test case fails i need to clear cookies from cypress dashboard browser i want to clear through script once it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as during the startup sequence you are performing the `cy.visit()` *after* you clear cookies, you should have no problem.

Make sure you use the **All** version to cover all domains

> Clear localStorage data for **all origins** with which the test has interacted.

The docs say that `clearAllCookies()` is asynchronous, so if you follow up with an assertion that cookies are empty, the test guarantee that the cleardown has happened.

Also make sure to have `testIsolation` on, in fact Cypress should be removing session data automatically for you.

```js
describe('My Test Suite', {testIsolation:true}, () => {

beforeEach(() => {

  cy.clearAllCookies()
  cy.getAllCookies().should('be.empty')

  cy.clearAllLocalStorage()
  cy.getAllLocalStorage().should('be.empty')

  cy.clearAllSessionStorage()
  cy.getAllSessionStorage().should('be.empty')

  // now you can visit the baseUrl
  cy.fixture('login').then(data => {
    cy.login(data.UserName, data.Password)
  })
})
```

`afterEach()` is not recommended for cleardown precisely for that reason - test fails might block the afterEach hook.

Comment: I have tried the approach as you have mentioned but it did not worked once my Test case fails i need to clear cookies manually & then once i re run the url loads 

Current Behaviour - If my Test case fails and if i re run from cypress dashboard it does not load url until & unless i clear the cookies manually

Comment: But please tell me *why* doing it **before** does not work?

Comment: It does not make sense, if you have shown the test accurately. Clearing down during startup has to have the same effect as clearing down after a test fail.